# Jenkins set build failed if number of tests decreases?

Tags: jenkins, junit, jenkins-plugins

Is there a way to mark a test run failed if the number of tests decreases in jenkins. We have a test report in JUnit.
For some reasons, sometimes the number of tests decreases. Often that are critical errors. Is there a way to say jenkins that in such case the test status should be red? (Maybe some plugin)

Thanks a lot for any hint!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a way.

Install the [Groovy Postbuild Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/Groovy+Postbuild+Plugin) and add a Post Build Step

**Post-Build-Actions -> Add Step -> Groovy Postbuild**

```
import jenkins.model.*

def currentBuild = manager.build
def totalCurrent 
def totalPrevious

// evaluate test count of current Build
def result = currentBuild .getAction(hudson.tasks.junit.TestResultAction.class).result
if (result != null) {
  totalCurrent = result.hasProperty( 'totalCount' ) ? result.totalCount : null
} 

// evaluate test count of previous Build
result = currentBuild .previousBuild.getAction(hudson.tasks.junit.TestResultAction.class).result
if (result != null) {
  totalPrevious = result.hasProperty( 'totalCount' ) ? result.totalCount : null
} 

// fail the build if test count reduced
if(totalCurrent < totalPrevious) {
  manager.buildFailure()
}
```

You'll may need to add some more nullsafe checks.

Answer (score -1):

Even if there is a way to do this, it sounds like a bad idea considering the fact that your number of tests executed could actually decrease from build to build for legitimate reasons.

First I would try to find out *why* this is happening unexpectedly.

Comment: I mean in our case the amount of tests doesn't decrease and if so it happens only from time to time. We do not know why sometimes this happens. Its a complicated and messy process behind the junit file creation. Even with mature frameworks sometimes it happens that for some reason's not all tests are running. If this happens I think it is a good Idea to get at least a warning! Or give you an example. Lets say a developer did a bad job and deleted a lot of tests and made his commit on the master branch. Now at least jenkins should give a final warning.